# Clicking on the padding of an input field sets the cursor at the beginning of the line, not at the end

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a HTML input field that has some padding defined, clicking on the padding area sets the cursor at the beginning of the line and not at the end.
Why is that happening? What would be a use case for this behaviour?
Any idea on how to prevent this and move always the cursor at the end of the line?

[image]

```
<input style="padding:25px;font-size:25px" value="hello" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sf4x3uzL/1

Comment: Tested in lastest Chrome and Firefox and Windows and works as expected. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Any browser; you are supposed to click on the higher end of the input area, near the upper border

Comment: I'm getting proper behavior in IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10. This might be an OS-dependent issue. In any case, I wouldn't write code to try to fix it, as you might just break inputs and slow down devices where the issues isn't present.

Comment: I, as well, seem to be unable to reproduce the issue on the browsers on my machine

Comment: I can confirm that I was able to reproduce this on Mac. But on Windows, it works as most people would expect it to work. I agree with @Domino in that writing code to fix this might bring additional issues.

Comment: What about a CSS only workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the snippet, the code is bit long but manages to work in all scenarios.

Here added a function to check if the click is from padding area from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462712/detecting-click-event-on-padding-only)

Added another function to get the caret position, and combined both function to get get the desired result.

```js
var carPos = 0;
(function($) {
  var isPaddingClick = function(element, e) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
    var pTop = parseInt( style.getPropertyValue('padding-top') );
    var pRight = parseFloat( style.getPropertyValue('padding-right') );
    var pLeft = parseFloat( style.getPropertyValue('padding-left') );  
    var pBottom = parseFloat( style.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom') );
    var width = element.offsetWidth;
    var height = element.offsetHeight;
    var x = parseFloat( e.offsetX );
    var y = parseFloat( e.offsetY );  
    return !(( x > pLeft && x < width - pRight) &&
             ( y > pTop && y < height - pBottom))
  }
  $.fn.paddingClick = function(fn) {
    this.on('click', function(e) {
      if (isPaddingClick(this, e)) {
       e.target.setSelectionRange(carPos, carPos);
        fn()
      }
    })   
    return this
  }
}(jQuery));


$('input').paddingClick()
$('input').bind('click keyup', function(event){
  carPos = event.target.selectionStart;
})
```

```css
.as-console{ display:none!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="padding:25px;font-size:25px" value='hello' />
```

Comment: the thing is this happens not only with paddings, regular input also works like this

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) to set the position of the cursor to the end of the input element on click.

```js
input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Do not do anything if the user already has a selection range,
  // for instance from a double click.
  const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = input;
  if (selectionStart !== selectionEnd) return;
  
  const { length } = input.value;
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(length, length);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" style="padding:25px;font-size:25px" value="hello" />
```

Comment: You may also want to add an event listener to the `focus` event to also handle the `Tab` key (see: https://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/t8cdwzfr/). Note: You can't seem to use `setSelectionRange` in a `focus` event handler in Chrome without adding a delay, eg: `setTimeout(() => input.setSelectionRange(length, length), 0)`

Comment: With your solution, clicking anywhere in the text field moves your cursor to the end.

Comment: Updated my answer, and here's an adjusted fiddle that also addresses the `Tab` key as noted above - https://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/45renbmz/

Comment: Keeping the cursor at the end behavior I'd expect, the problem with this solution is that is not possible to select the whole with a double click. 
Any idea why the browsers behave like this?

Comment: Updated my answer to support double-clicking (as well as dragging). Also, I changed the behavior back to moving the cursor to the end of the input.

Comment: I think this is the best solution if I really want to get rid of that behavior, thanks. Still wondering why this the default behavior though.

Comment: @ManuelBitto how come this be the best solution. how can you edit the text or remove text in between the words with this solution.

Comment: @AkhilAravind you are right, I didn't notice that problem before

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

```js
$("input").click(function(){
  this.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to set to 0 the vertical padding and adjust the line-height to get the correct height of the input.

This solution is suitable for input only: in case of textarea the huge line-height might be a problem.

```html
<input style="padding:0 25px; line-height:3.48; font-size:25px" value="hello" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you click on the top part of the padding

Comment: -_- ...I hate Chrome.
You're right.
This works properly in Firefox and I assumed that other browser behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) to set the caret position at the end using [-1 , -1] position.

```html
<input style="padding:25px;font-size:25px;border:1px solid #c0d9bc;outline:2px solid #6fae62" onclick="this.setSelectionRange(-1,-1)" value="hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this at stack only but seems to be a decent solution, which always sets the value and cursor to end of the text.

```
<input style="padding:25px;font-size:25px" value="hello" 
 onfocus="this.value = this.value;" />.
```

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, clicking on the padding is still *as* clicking on the `<input>` itself. It seems like what's happening next depends on some specific implementation in the Browser or the OS. For example, on macOS + Chrome it behaves the way you describe, but it may happen that in Windows it behaves differently.
My approach would be a CSS only, though.

First, wrap your input within a label, this is important, so that if you click on the *virtual padding* the `<input>` will get the focus automatically.

```
<label class="custom-input">
  <input value='Hello' />
</label>
```

And finally the CSS:

```
.custom-input {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 25px;
}

.custom-input > input {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 0 none;
  outline: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4ysdt7z0/17/

Comment: Interesting, but this removes the default behavior on Windows which is to place the cursor in the input based on where you clicked, even when clicking the padding.

Answer (score 0):

I can also reproduce this behavior on both Chrome and Safari, using a MacBook Pro.

My workaround for this, not tested cross-device but at least cross-browser, is to set the vertical spacing of the field using line-height, instead padding:

So instead of `padding: .75rem;`, I used:

```
padding: 0 .75rem;
line-height: 2.5rem;
```

This is not a complete fix, because clicking the border of the input will still set the cursor to index 0, but at least it works better for me than vertical padding.